# Implement webservice for login with social sites

Tags: php, facebook, web-services, twitter

I am working with the webservies for ios and android app and need to develop a service for login with social media.

The app need to support login with twitter, facebook, linkedin, and google plus.

As parameters, I am accepting userid from social site and the site from which this id originated and the basic user info like firstname, lastname, and email.

Below is the structure of relevant tables for this

1. user table

   userid |  email | deviceid | firstname | lastname | password

userid being primary and email is unique

2. user social media table

   userid | site | token

When I get this information from the frontend, I first check if social user id is already there. If social id doesn't match then I check if email exists in db or not. If email is not in the db, then I register the new user.

Now the main issue is that the twitter sdk for android and ios does not return the email and even facebook does not return the email if the user is registered by phone, because of this I am having a problem uniquely identifying the user on my end. I have searched a lot but can't come up with any solution for this.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere in my approach and suggest to me how can I handle the email issue.

Comment: @usumoio frontend guys are sending userid direcly so I dont need to use oauth at my end .Anyways what will u suggest ?

Comment: Dang, that was just a shoot in the dark. Do the SDK docs mention anything about including additional parameters like email via additional modifiers?

Comment: @usumoio I don't think so .. I was just thinking if there is anything that is returned by all sdks that can help me to uniquely identify the user  or how should I handle this ?

Comment: You should use the user id those external services return to identify users in your system.

Comment: @CBroe I can surely do that but in that case social accounts registered with same email will have different data in my app. Say a person is registered with acb@xyz.com in facebook and twitter. Now facebook will return email and I will register an account with abc@xyz.com .Next user login on twitter with same account but since twitter does not return me email I have to create new account and no data will be shown to this user  though user is same

Comment: Then tell your users, that to connect those two different accounts, they should login to your site with one first, and then connect to the other – so that you know, they belong to the same user

Comment: @CBroe hmm .. seems it is  not possible to come up with any other solution :(

Comment: No, there is little else that would allow you to uniquely identify any user across social networks. And even if you get an email address, they might have used different ones to sign up for different networks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have used 1 table for both types of users instead, like this:

```
userid | type | email | socialid | deviceid | firstname | lastname | password | token
```

**'type'** column would be an **enum** of possible account types: **fb**, **twitter**, **google** or **email**

**'socialid'** would have an id from social network (the id is included in oauth response) for users coming from those and will be **null** for normal users(registered via email)

**'email'** would include an email for normal users and be **null** for social users

Then it's just a matter of SELECT query to understand what type of user you're working with

Comment: Then a user with two social ids will have de normalize record in your table.

Comment: In my example i dind't suppose binding different accounts together, but if you need this, you'll have to stick to 2-table structure

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ and implement to suite your architecture or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Facebook API should ship with the users ID. Twitter SDK is a bit tricky. Try to save the userers Twitter-username in your database.